# Why did Yoda and Palpatine talk about Anakin?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious, yoda

At the beginning of [Duel in the Senate](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Duel_in_the_Galactic_Senate) Yoda enters Chancellor's office and says:

> - I hear a new apprentice you have, Emperor. Or, should I call you Darth Sidious?

Later, they exchange these words:

> - You will not stop me. Darth Vader will become more powerful than either of us.
> - Faith in your new apprentice, misplaced may be, as is your faith in the dark side of the Force.

All this sounds a bit weird, looks like they are fighting over Anakin (who would control him), not because eternal enmity between Jedi and Sith. Remember, Palpatine just orchestrated killing of so many Jedi, Anakin killed younglings, yet Yoda doesn't mention anything of that. He sounds almost like Palpatine stole  his new shiny toy, and he wants it back. 
  On the other hand, Palpatine admits that Anakin would become more powerful then he is. Yet, he doesn't seem to be upset about that, he sounds glad - very strange for a Sith.

Comment: It reads like a hamfisted way of hinting/foreshadowing that Anakin will one day kill Palpatine, even if neither character knows it at the time. From Palpatine's viewpoint, his part at least could just be gloating.

Comment: @Jack Please write full answer, and elaborate more on this ;)

Comment: In any of the Star Wars prequel films it's probably more interesting to ask about instances when the dialogue *does* make sense.

Comment: From my understanding, the whole point of a sith master taking an apprentice is for them to eventually overthrow them, it's how it has been since Darth Bane, so Sidious would know this, and if Vader is more powerful, then that would just lead to the strengthening of the Sith's grasp over the galaxy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anakin has the most force potential of any force user in the galaxy, and is believed by the Jedi to be the prophesied chosen one who will bring balance to the force (first mentioned in episode 1). As such, he would be seen as pretty important to the Jedi's fight with the Sith.

The first quote is probably just Yoda making Sidious aware that he knows Anakin has betrayed the Jedi, and that Sidious is a Sith. Basically that he knows what is going on. Nothing terribly unusual here.

From Sidious' perspective, recruiting him is a major coup and worth gloating about. Certainly, Sidious is commenting on his potential here. Given the Sith have the whole rule of two going on where in theory each apprentice will ultimately succeed their master and prove themselves the stronger, the expectation that Anakin/Vader will become stronger than Sidious is not so strange.

Finally, the last quote suggests that Yoda still places some hope in the prophecy, and that Anakin may still bring balance by destroying Sidious. At this point, most of the audience should have seen Return of the Jedi, so we know this actually happens. Out of universe, it is most likely intended to foreshadow this.

It is also worth noting that George Lucas has stated that he views Star Wars as being to [story of Anakin](http://www.latimes.com/entertainment/la-et-lucas7-2008may07-story.html). While it is possible that this wasn't always the case (he seems to have had a habit of changing his mind), it is now his publicly stated opinion. This is likely to have influenced his focus here around Anakin.

Comment: In all honesty I had more interpreted yodas comment, that the apprentice will fail as will the dark side of the force and less like "the prophecy will hold true"